# Return all elements on nesting depth n of a nested list

Tags: list, scheme, nested, racket, depth

I'm really puzzled on how to do this... I can't even figure out how to start, I know how to do it for a binary tree but I want to be able to do it with any form of nested list, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: I want it to work for a list like: 
(1 (2 (3 4) 5 6 7 (8 (5 6) 9)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one, you need to use the template for traversing an arbitrarily nested list of elements. For example, study this procedure that copies an arbitrarily nested list:

```
(define (copy lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)                ; if list is empty
         '())                       ; return the empty list
        ((not (list? (car lst)))    ; if current element is not a list
         (cons (car lst)            ; cons current element
               (copy (cdr lst))))   ; with the rest of the list
        (else                       ; if current element is a list
         (cons (copy (car lst))     ; cons recursive call over current element
               (copy (cdr lst)))))) ; with recursive call over rest of the list
```

A little convention first. Let's say that `1` is the base level, and that all the elements returned will be in a flat output list (without preserving the original structure of the input list). For example:

```
(elements-level '(1 2 3) 1)
; => '(1 2 3)

(elements-level '(1 (2) 3) 2)
; => '(2)
```

With the above template in mind, let's see how we can modify it for solving the problem at hand. I'll let you fill-in the blanks, because the question looks like homework:

```
(define (elements-level lst lvl)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (< lvl 1))        ; if list is empty or below level
         '())                              ; return the empty list
        ((not (list? (car lst)))           ; if current element is not a list
         (if (= lvl <???>)                 ; if `lvl` is the base level
             (cons <???>                   ; cons current element in list
               (elements-level <???> lvl)) ; and advance recursion over cdr part
             (elements-level <???> lvl)))  ; else advance recursion over cdr part
        (else                              ; if current element is a list
         (append                           ; use `append` for flattening the list
          (elements-level <???> <???>)     ; recur over car, decrease one level
          (elements-level <???> <???>))))) ; recur over cdr, keep the same level
```

Test the procedure with this list, it must return `'(1)` for level `1`, `'(2)` for level `2`, and so on:

```
(elements-level '(1 (2 (3 (4 (5))))) 1)
; => '(1)
```

Comment: With what I filled in the blanks it works for your example but not for mine, I'm using this list: 
'(leeg (kaars (leeg (ster)(leeg)) (bal)) (ster (ster) (leeg (kaars) (leeg)) (bal)) (kaars (bal) (leeg (leeg) (ster))                  (kaars (leeg) (leeg)))))

Comment: what's the expected output for that list? for what level?

Comment: first lvl being 0, it should return for lvl 2: (leeg, bal, ster, leeg, bal, bal, leeg, kaars)

Comment: first lvl being 0, it should return for lvl 1: (kaars, ster, kaars)

Comment: that wasn't it, I made a mistake in the last line, was also decreasing the level there, thankyou very much for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use recursion with steps as below:

1. Define a list to hold all elements at nth depth.
2. create a recursion function, which takes `nested list`, `new list` and `n` as argument
3. For each element of the nested loop, call the recursion function itself by passing the child list and depth as n-1.
4. Add all elements of the `nested list` to `new list` when n = 0.

Once this method is done, you will all elements of depth `n` in the `new list`.

**Possible Enhancement:**
If it is possible the some of the list elements don't extend up to nth level, then you may want to check the type of elements before calling the recursion method. If it's of type leaf, then simply add the element in the new list.

Comment: Thanks fr the comment but i don't really get how to code what you said, this is what I would make of it but i'm rather sure it won't work                                                                (define (rec nestedlst newlst n)
  (if (= n 0)
      nestedlst
      (cond ((null? nestedlst) nestedlst)
            ((atom? nestedlst) nestedlst)
            (else (append (rec (car nestedlst) newlst (- n 1))
                          (rec (cdr nestedlst) newlst (- n 1)))))))

Comment: @Daquicker: Which part you don't get and which one you think will not work?